# SQL Combining two Queries and Trying to find the avg price of similar tickers and sides on the same trade date

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, trading

I am trying to find trying to find the avg price of similar tickers and sides on the same Trade date from two different queries. I combined them using union but for some reason do not know what to do further.

Here is my data for a given data and my code:

```
TradeDate   Ticker  Side    Quantity    Price
11/04/2020  AMAG    Buy      6100        13.6704
11/04/2020  EIGI    BUY      7325         9.3569
11/04/2020  EIGI    Buy       175         9.35
11/04/2020  HUD     BUY     23594         7.6514
11/04/2020  HUD     Buy     83406         7.64973670958924
11/04/2020  MR      BUY     15000         4.8196
11/04/2020  MYOK    BUY       130       224.5866
11/04/2020  MYOK    Buy      3870       224.300348837209
```

```
(SELECT TradeDate, Ticker, Side, TotalQuantity as Quantity, AvgPrice  as Price
FROM  AllTradesCitadel)
UNION  (SELECT TradeDate, Ticker, Side, Quantity, Price
FROM AllTradesTradeBook);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in SQL, you can run the union as a derived table (a select query in `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses), layered within an aggregate query.

```sql
SELECT TradeDate
        , Ticker
        , Side
        , SUM(Quantity) AS Total_Qty
        , AVG(Price) AS Avg_Price
FROM
   (SELECT TradeDate, Ticker, Side, TotalQuantity AS Quantity, AvgPrice AS Price
    FROM  AllTradesCitadel
    UNION
    SELECT TradeDate, Ticker, Side, Quantity, Price
    FROM AllTradesTradeBook
   ) sub
GROUP BY TradeDate
         , Ticker
         , Side
```

Specifically for MS Access, due to performance reasons avoid any union queries as nested record sources. Therefore, create a table via [make-table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-make-table-query-96424f9e-82fd-411e-aca4-e21ad0a94f1b) action query using `INTO` directive. Then run your final aggregation query on compiled table.

**Create Table** *(action command that returns no results)*

```
SELECT sub.TradeDate, sub.Ticker, sub.Side, sub.Quantity, sub.Price
INTO allTradesData
FROM
   (SELECT TradeDate, Ticker, Side, TotalQuantity as Quantity, AvgPrice  as Price
    FROM  AllTradesCitadel
    UNION  
    SELECT TradeDate, Ticker, Side, Quantity, Price
    FROM AllTradesTradeBook
   ) sub
```

**Final Aggregation**

```sql
SELECT TradeDate
        , Ticker
        , Side
        , SUM(Quantity) AS Total_Qty
        , AVG(Price) AS Avg_Price
FROM allTradesData
GROUP BY TradeDate
         , Ticker
         , Side
```

Comment: I see what you are doing but i need it to also only do it if thte trade date is the same you are doing it for all of the data i need it to be done per trade date.

Comment: Then simply add `Trade_Date` to `SELECT` and  `GROUP BY`. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
select TradeDate, Ticker, Side, sum(Quantity), avg(Price) from 
(SELECT TradeDate, Ticker, Side, TotalQuantity as Quantity, AvgPrice  as Price
FROM  AllTradesCitadel
UNION ALL  SELECT TradeDate, Ticker, Side, Quantity, Price
FROM AllTradesTradeBook) t group by TradeDate, Ticker, Side
```